# How to generate view from library project in Android

Tags: android, android-library

My requirement is to generate view based on the response type inside Library. Library has to return single view based on whether the response is image or text (creation should happen inside library). I have created the library project, parse the response but I am not sure how to return the view from a library project to app which is implementing.
Should I create a custom view class inside library and use listener and on success add in the UI which is implementing the library.

How can I approach this problem any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Shanthi

Comment: you want to return view alone . right ?

Comment: ya so the library should return whether it is image or text view.

Comment: are you having problem making a view in library ? i can help you with that .But im not sure what are you planning to achieve .

Comment: Hi Rohit, yes basically I need to make a single view based on whether the response is Image or text and return that view to any project which is implementing the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a custom View the skeleton looks like this

```
 public abstract class YourClass extends View {

   private Context context;

   public YourClass(Context context) {
     super(context);
      initialize(context);
   }

    public YourClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      initialize(context);
   }

   public YourClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       initialize(context);
   }

   private void abstract initialize(Context context);
   // PROVIDE IMPLEMENTATION BASED ON RESPONSE 
}
```

Then make concrete class which will extends this class

eq

```
ImageClass extends Your class{

    public void initialize(Context context)
    {
        View view = inflate(context, R.layout.imageViewLayout , this);
    }
}
```

or

```
TextClass extends Your class{

        public void initialize(Context context)
        {
            View view = inflate(context, R.layout.textViewLayout , this);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

> HERE is a tutorial for reference [How to make library project](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582)

Again there could be different ways returning the view.
You can pass some value in **constructor** and based on that value you can inflate view in **initialize()** method, there you don't need to make several child classes but that will be a tightly coupled design.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. will try out and let you know.

Comment: happy to help :)